# How to copy Wampserver functionality for localhost on Ubuntu

Tags: server, ubuntu, localhost, wampserver

How to recreate a Wampserver like functionality on my localhost so I can see loaded Apache/PHP/MySQL Version, Loaded PHP modules, My Projects (actual directories in the "/var/www"/) and etc.

Comment: That link is showing access denied. Also, can you clarify your question a bit? Wampserver suggests you already are on localhost. Are you asking how to install Apache, etc., on an Ubuntu server?

Comment: on fresh install of Wampserver when you visit your localhost you can see a page with the following information: Server Information, Apache/PHP/MySQL Version, Loaded Extensions, Tools, Your Projects (which are the directories in your "www"), Your Aliases (PhpMyAdmin). I want to recreate this in my LAMP if it's possible

Comment: Look at xampp for ubuntu

Comment: I already have Apache,MySQL,PHP installed and running. I'm looking only for solution similar to WampServer when I open http://localhost. Would it be a standalone application or custom written script it doesn't matter

Comment: You mean a summary of the services running / phpMyAdmin / what exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have migrated your files and database to Ubuntu, you can create a php file with `phpinfo();` inside the file. View this in your browser and it will show you all the loaded php modules.

For a list of loaded apache2 modules open a terminal and type `apache2ctl -M`

To lookup your MySQL version there are a number of ways listed here http://www.geeksww.com/tutorials/database_management_systems/mysql/tips_and_tricks/how_to_check_mysql_version_number.php

But from your mysql> prompt type `SELECT version();`